# How to open dropdown menu on a button click? html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a drop down menu on the navigation bar to open up when a button is pressed. Currently got:

```
<script>
  $('#broadcaster').click(function() {

      $('#menu2 a').dropdown("toggle");
  });

</script>
```

Broadcaster being the button ID & menu2 the ID for the list of the dropdown.
Right now, it shows the menu being clicked when the button is clicked but the menu does not open up. Also tried various like   `$('#menu2 a').click();`
Rather avoid more css, any suggestions?

Here is the drop down element:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown" id="menu2">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2">
       Register
       <b class="caret"></b>
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <form role="form" action="/user/create" method="post">
         <fieldset id="menu4" class='textbox' style="width: ; padding:10px;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newNameInput">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="newName" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newEmailInput">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="newEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newPasswordInput">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="newPassword" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" value="Sign Up" id="signup" type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think there is dropdown() method. Perhaps you wanted to use toggle() method instead.

Comment: can you provide HTML code / LINK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.dropdown').click(function() {

      $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('#broadcaster').click(function() {

      $('#menu2 a').bind('click',functionName());
  });
```

Define `functionName` below, it will work.

Comment: what would the functionName do exactly ?

Comment: You can write the functionality of drop down here.

Comment: that's really what I was asking to begin with, what is the function/method that I can go to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this.. try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#broadcaster').click(function() {

      $('#menu2 a').dropdown("toggle");
  });
});
```